# Delete row if type cast fails

Tags: sql, postgresql, exception, plpgsql, uuid

Ok, here is the layout:
I have a bunch of `uuid` data that is in `varchar` format. I know `uuid` is its own type.  This is how I got the data. So to verify this which ones are `uuid`, I take the `uuid` in type `varchar` and insert it into a table where the column is `uuid`. If the insert fails, then it is not a `uuid` type. My basic question is how to delete the bad `uuid` if the insert fails. Or, how do I delete out of one table if an insert fails in another table.
My first set of data:

```
drop table if exists temp1;
drop sequence if exists temp1_id_seq;
CREATE temp table temp1 (id serial, some_value varchar);
INSERT INTO temp1(some_value) 
SELECT split_part(name,':',2) FROM branding_resource WHERE name LIKE '%curric%';
create temp table temp2 (id serial, other_value uuid);

CREATE OR REPLACE function verify_uuid() returns varchar AS $$
DECLARE uu RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR uu IN  select * from temp1 
LOOP
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO temp2 values ('||uu.id||','''|| uu.some_value||''')';
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
select verify_uuid();
```

When I run this, I get the error

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid:

which is what I expect.  There are some bad uuids in my data set.

My research led me to [Trapping Errors - Exceptions with `UPDATE`/`INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) in the docs.
Narrowing down to the important part:

```
BEGIN
FOR uu IN  select * from temp1 
LOOP
    begin
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO temp2 values ('||uu.id||','''|| uu.some_value||''')';
    return;
    exception when ??? then delete from temp1 where some_value = uu.some_value;
    end;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I do not know what to put instead of `???`. I think it relates to the `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid:`, but I am not sure. I am actually not even sure if this is the right way to go about this?

Comment: Your version of Postgres would be essential.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the SQLSTATE code from `psql` using `VERBOSE` mode, e.g:

```
regress=> \set VERBOSITY verbose
regress=> SELECT 'fred'::uuid;
ERROR:  22P02: invalid input syntax for uuid: "fred"
LINE 1: SELECT 'fred'::uuid;
               ^
LOCATION:  string_to_uuid, uuid.c:129
```

Here we can see that the `SQLSTATE` is `22P02`. You can use that directly in the exception clause, but it's generally more readable to [look it up in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) to find the text representation. Here, we see that `22P02` is `invalid_text_representation`.

So you can write `exception when invalid_text_representation then` ...

Answer (score 1):

[@Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23258262/939860) shows a way to identify the `SQLSTATE`.
You an also use pgAdmin, which shows the `SQLSTATE` by default:

```
SELECT some_value::uuid FROM temp1

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for uuid: "-a0eebc999c0b4ef8bb6d6bb9bd380a11"
> SQL state: 22P02
```

I am going to address the bigger question:

> I am actually not even sure if this is the right way to go about this?

Your basic approach is the right way: the `'parking in new york' method` ([quoting Merlin Moncure in this thread on pgsql-general](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4AE218A9.6020209@gmail.com#4AE218A9.6020209@gmail.com)). But the procedure is needlessly expensive. Probably much faster:

#### Exclude obviously violating strings immediately.

You should be able to weed out the lion's share of violating strings with a much cheaper regexp test.
[Postgres accepts a couple of different formats for UUID in `text` representation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html), but as far as I can tell, this character class should covers *all* valid characters:

```
'[^A-Fa-f0-9{}-]'
```

You can probably narrow it down further for your particular brand of UUID representation (Only lower case? No curly braces? No hyphen?).

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 (id serial, some_value text);

INSERT INTO temp1 (some_value) 
SELECT split_part(name,':',2)
FROM   branding_resource
WHERE  name LIKE '%curric%'
AND    split_part(name,':',2) !~ '[^A-Fa-f0-9{}-]';
```

*"Does not contain illegal characters."*

#### Cast to test the rest

Instead of filling another table, it should be much cheaper to just delete (*the now few!*) violating rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function f_kill_bad_uuid()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   rec record;
BEGIN
FOR rec IN
   SELECT * FROM temp1 
LOOP
   BEGIN
   PERFORM rec.some_value::uuid;             -- no dynamic SQL needed
                                             -- do not RETURN! Keep looping.
   RAISE NOTICE 'Good: %', rec.some_value;   -- only for demo
   EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Bad: %', rec.some_value; -- only for demo
      DELETE FROM temp1 WHERE some_value = rec.some_value;
   END;
END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- No need for dynamic SQL. Just *cast*. Use [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT), since we are not interested in the result. We just want to see if the cast goes through or not.
- Not return value. You *could* count and return the number of excluded rows ...
- For a one-time operation you could also use a [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement.
- And do not quote the language name `'plpgsql'`. It's an identifier, not a string.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/db6af/2)